# How do I convert char ** to a char *[] in c?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, execv

The `execv` function takes an array of pointers as a second parameter. I have a pointer to a pointer, a dynamically created string list.

How do I create an array of pointers from this?

```
char **list = malloc((argc)*sizeof(char*));
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<argc;++i){ // using argv for example...
 list[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i])+1);
 strcpy(list[i], argv[i]);
}
// create from list an array of pointers
execv(list_pointers[0], list_pointers);
```

Otherwise I get a Bad address error if passing in simply `list` to `execv`.

Comment: How about using `(char*[]) list_pointers` ??

Comment: I can just cast the list?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. Just try it...

Comment: And don't forget to cast `list+1` (which is probably what you meant to do).

Comment: I get the error cast specifies array type with `(char*[])list`.

Comment: The type of `list` is assignment compatible with the type of second argument of `execv` which is `char * const *`. What error message you get when you simply pass `list`?

Comment: This should work, I think you should just `execv(list[0], list+1)` does this result in `Bad address` ?

Comment: @user1561108 How are you calling `execv`? The first argument should be a pointer to the file name. Also, the second argument which is an array of pointers must be terminated by a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Got it: `malloc((argc+1)*sizeof(char*));` then no need for a `+1` on the `execv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the function `execv` declared in the header `unistd.h` is

```
int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
```

Please note that this is the same as

```
int execv(const char *path, char *const *argv);
```

which means that `argv` is a pointer to an object of type `char * const`, i.e., a constant pointer to a character. Also, the man page of `execv` says -

> The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename
>   associated with the file being executed.  The array of pointers must
>   be terminated by a NULL pointer.

Also, `list`, whose  type is `char **`, is assignment compatible with the second argument of `execv`. I suggest the following changes -

```
// +1 for the terminating NULL pointer required for the 
// second argument of execv

char **list = malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof *list); 
if(list == NULL) {
    printf("not enough memory to allocate\n");
    // handle it
}
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
    // strdup returns a pointer to a new string
    // which is a duplicate of the string argv[i]
    // this does effectively the same as the commented 
    // out block after the below statement.
    // include the header string.h for the prototype
    // of strdup POSIX function.

    list[i] = strdup(argv[i]);

    /* 
    list[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i])+1);
    if(list[i] == NULL) {
        printf("not enough memory to allocate\n");
        // handle it
    }
    strcpy(list[i], argv[i]);
    */
}

list[argc] = NULL;  // terminate the array with the NULL pointer
execv(list[0], list);
```

Comment: I added the +1 in the malloc statement but didn't assign list[argc] NULL or add +1 to the execv 2nd parameter and it still worked as expected. Is that equivalent to what you have above and if so why?

Comment: @user1561108 I updated my answer. The second argument should not have +1 added to it. The array of pointers pointed to by the second argument of `execv` must be NULL-terminated else it will invoke undefined behaviour. I think you are just lucky to have it NULL-terminated in the case you ran the program.

Comment: On POSIX compliant systems, you can simplify the body of the loop to `list[i] = strdup(argv[i]);`, the `strdup()` function combines the calls to `strlen()`, `malloc()`, and `strcpy()`. Also note that it only clutters the code to check the return value of `malloc()`: modern systems overcommit their memory, so `malloc()` generally always succeeds, it's only when you access memory that your process may get shot down by the OOM-killer. And checking the return value of `malloc()` can't protect you from that.

Comment: @cmaster True. Memory overcommit is always a problem with `malloc` and the check for `NULL` does not us save from it. However, sometimes there's no better option than using `malloc`. I have updated my answer to use `strdup` instead of `malloc` for copying strings. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, memory overcommit is not only a problem of `malloc`, it bites C++ programs using `new` just as well. There is simply no such thing as safety when doing an allocation. Both safety mechanisms (checking the return value of `malloc` and catching exceptions from `new`) simply won't work. So, why bother using them? You crash either way.

Answer (score 1):

From execv man page:

"The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer."

The function execv doesn't know the argument count

```
 char **list = malloc((argc+1)*sizeof(char*));
 if (list == NULL) {
     abort();
 }
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<argc;++i){ // using argv for example...
     if ((list[i] = strdup(argv[i])) == NULL) {
         abort();
     }
 }
 list[argc] = NULL;
 execv(list[0], list);
```

EDIT
I also removed list+1 from the execv call, thanks for @ajay for finding it